# Faster code for checking repeated values in a JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance

```
var valueArray = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','ABC','JKL','MNO','DEF'];
var flag =false;
for(var i=0; i<valueArray.length; i++)
{
   for(var j=0; j<valueArray.length; j++)
  {
     if(valueArray[j] == valueArray[i] && j != i)
     {
          flag  = true;
          break;
     }
  }
}
if(flag)
    alert('same values found');
```

I am trying to validate one array by checking for duplicate values, i used above code, i don't think its a better way. is there any ways with `jquery` for this or some good `js` codes for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: @chriz NOPE.. http://jsfiddle.net/C7rK9/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but i dont want to remove duplicates just want to check..

Comment: "Better" by what criteria? Faster? Easier to understand? Easy to maintain? Most compatible with old browsers? Not dependent on a library?

Comment: @RobG `FASTER` and easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about jquery, but performance will be better with just one for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++)
{
  if (valueArray.indexOf(valueArray[i], i+1) != -1) {
    flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

jsPerf test: http://jsperf.com/check-for-double-occurences

Comment: @openorclosw great impressed

Comment: The tests are not particularly good since the first element in the array is the duplicated element, so methods like *indexOf* and using *sort* are only called once, whereas the looping methods are called at least 4 times. Much fairer to put the duplicate in the middle to emulate an average case where the duplicate could appear anywhere in the array. Compare with the results [*here*](http://jsperf.com/has-duplicates). Also, performance is hugely affected by the browser in use.

Comment: Yeah no wonder my answer was so much faster than yours so it was just due to the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast, compatible, "works everywhere" function that just checks for duplicates and doesn't require any library, consider:

```
function hasDups(arr) {

  // Firstly copy array so don't affect original, then sort
  var t = arr.slice().sort();

  // If adjacent members have the same value, return true
  for (var i=1, iLen=t.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (t[i] === t[i-1]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasDups(['abc','dvf','abc'])); // true
```

However you might want something a little more functional, e.g. that you can provide a compare function to so that, say, `'abc' == 'ABC'` or `'5' == 5`.

Or if you want to use new features and avoid the copy and sort, consider:

```
function hasDups2(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  return arr.some(function(v){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(v)) return true;
    obj[v] = '';
  });
}
```

The same strategy can be applied to the first as well and avoid ES5's *some*.

Note that both the above are only really suitable for comparing primitive values, though the first is better for that. If you want a reliable function to look for duplicate objects, that requires a bit more work.

Comment: sry i think openorclose's answer deserves accept.. its more simple.

Comment: @chriz—how so? It's more code and runs at 1/3 to 1/4 the speed of the above solutions (depending on the browser), see [*http://jsperf.com/has-duplicates*](http://jsperf.com/has-duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery.unique()` and compare the array size. If the size of the resultant array is not the same then return false.

Doc for [jquery.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/)

Comment: @Chris: Actually tested this. It is working. However you are right as this may not be an efficient answer since it is not meant for the purpose.